# Is there a cleaner way to do this loop?

Tags: python, django

Can any one help me come up with a solution that makes this loop simpler. The code runs fine but just seems too much for what it does.

```
    font_sizes = map(int, re.findall(r'\\fs(\d+)', rtf)) # Get all the font sizes
    # Set font sizes
    for font_size in font_sizes:
        font_size = (font_size / 2)
        if font_size <= 8:
                rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(1))
        else:
            if 9 <= font_size <= 11:
                rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(2))
            else:
                if 12 <= font_size <= 13:
                    rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(3))
                else:
                    if 14 <= font_size <= 17:
                        rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(4))
                    else:
                        if 18 <= font_size <= 31:
                            rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(5))
                        else:
                            if 32 <= font_size <= 34:
                                rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(6))
                            else:
                                if 35 <= font_size <= 59:
                                    rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(7))
                                else:
                                    if font_size > 60:
                                        rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(8))
                                    else:
                                        pass
```

Comment: Well, for a start: `elif`?!

Comment: Your code is not self-explanatory *at all*. What are you trying to do?!

Comment: create a mapping, a dictionary for example

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide: not really, you'd have 59 keys. There are far more efficient ways to handle this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I meant a range mapping, anyhow I didn't know about bisect, looks much cleaner, cool

Comment: You could use a list instead of a mapping. For these small numbers - a bytearray would be hard to beat

Comment: @gnibbler: we don't know up to what upper bound the font sizes can go; of course an `IndexError` handler could just use a default at that point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, It's a memory/speed trade off, I'd probably be happy to use an array for small values and overflow to a bisect for large ones if necessary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you can use `elif` to avoid having to nest so deeply:

```
if font_size <= 8:
    rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(1))

elif 9 <= font_size <= 11:
    rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(2))

elif 12 <= font_size <= 13:
    rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(3))

# etc
```

You can drop the `else: pass` altogether, `else` is optional and you should just omit it when not used.

Next, factor out the common element; the `str.replace()` call; all that differs between them is the replacement fontsize, pick *just that* in each branch:

```
if font_size <= 8:
    size = 1
elif 9 <= font_size <= 11:
    size = 2
elif 12 <= font_size <= 13:
    size = 3
# etc.

rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(size))
```

Far more readable as you are not repeating yourself all the time.

You can remove the lower bound each time, as you already eliminated the lower bound with the preceding test:

```
if font_size <= 8:
    size = 1
elif font_size <= 11:
    size = 2
elif font_size <= 13:
    size = 3
# etc.
```

Now all you have is a [bisection problem](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html); finding the size to go with a font-size is as simple as finding it's insertion point into a list of font_sizes; where you'd insert it is an index between 0 and 7, so you'd add 1:

```
import bisect

font_sizes = [8, 11, 13, 17, 31, 34, 59]
size = bisect.bisect_left(font_sizes, font_size) + 1
rtf = rtf.replace("\\fs{0}".format(font_size * 2), "<font size='{0}'>".format(size))
```

I'm not sure why you are dividing the font sizes by two; the above 3 lines work just fine with the font size *not* divided.

Since you are replacing elements, you should really use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) here, using a function to produce the replacement:

```
def insert_fontsize(match):
    font_sizes = [16, 22, 26, 34, 62, 68, 118]
    size = bisect.bisect_left(font_sizes, int(match.group(1))) + 1
    return '<font size="{0}">'.format(size)

re.sub(r'\\fs(\d+)', insert_fontsize, rtf)
```

Now the `re.sub()` call will do the looping, rather than you loop and then do manual replacements.

Comment: There's one more problem that happens if the string contains something like `r'\fs2\fs20'`. I would consider using `re.split` to isolate the font size tags.

Comment: `bisect` is the way to go.

Comment: @YannVernier: Or just use `re.sub()` instead.

Comment: Indeed, I just found out about how its function replacement works. Very nice.

Comment: Thanks for the range of solutions!